# Calling stored procedure in remote oracle DB via DBLINK

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dblink

I have faced a problem with calling procedure in another Oracle DB using DBLink.

I've created a DBLINK on DB2 TO DB1 named sourcelink:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK sourcelink
CONNECT TO TABLEMASTER IDENTIFIED BY "xxxxxx"
USING '(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = x.x.x.x)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
)
)';
```

ON DB1 I've created temporary table and procedure inserting to this table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TABLEMASTER.TMP_PARTITION_RECORDS
(
   PARTITION_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
   PARTITION_COUNT NUMBER(12)
);



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS(arg_owner_name VARCHAR2, arg_table_name VARCHAR2)
IS
   v_query VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   FOR v_query IN 
   (
      SELECT 'INSERT INTO TABLEMASTER.TMP_PARTITION_RECORDS(PARTITION_NAME, PARTITION_COUNT) SELECT A.partitionname, A.rowscount FROM (SELECT ' || CHR(39) || PARTITION_NAME || CHR(39) || ' as partitionname, count(*) as rowscount FROM ' || TABLE_OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME ||' partition (' || PARTITION_NAME || 
        ')) A' AS query_text 
      FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TESTTABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'TABLEMASTER'
   )
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query.query_text;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I can call this function from DB1 and it works perfectly:

```
BEGIN
    TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');
END;
```

But using DBLINK DB1 I can't execute it remotely from DB2 database (other host):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION()
IS 
  v_ret NUMBER(2);
BEGIN 
    TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');
END;
```

I get PROCEDURE TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION compilation error like:

> PLS-00201: identifier
> 'TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK' must be declared
> Compile error AT line 6, column 2   PL/SQL: Statement ignored Compile
> error AT line 6, column 2

But simple select using DBLINK DB1 (from DB2) works perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEMASTER.TMP_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK;
```

I've tried calling the procedure with different syntax inside TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION():

```
v_variable := TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');

EXECUTE TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');

EXEC TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
That was problem with my DBLINK - it was not public. After recreating DBLINK with public syntax I can access my procedure.

Comment: The PLS-00201 message you've included implies the whole thing was a single identifier, enclosed in double-quotes? Without quotes I think it would report "'TABLEMASTER@SOURCELINK' must be declared" but not sure and can't verify. But you shouldn't need the `TABLEMASTER.` prefix, as that's the schema you're connecting to anyway.

Comment: You're right Alex - enclosing procedure name in double-quotes returns PLS-00201 "'TABLEMASTER@SOURCELINK' must be declared". Any idea how to properly call this procedure using my dblink? Maybe this is stupid question but I am not used to OracleDB.

Comment: The error suggest that you call `"TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK"('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');` if you quote it *must*  be  as follows `"TABLEMASTER"."INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS"@"SOURCELINK"('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');`

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION(arg_owner_name varchar2, arg_table_name varchar2)
IS 
BEGIN 
     "TABLEMASTER"."INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS"@"SOURCELINK"('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');
END;`
doesn't compile aswell with errors:
 
_PLS-00201: identifier 'TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS@SOURCELINK' must be declared
Compile error at line 4, column 7
 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Compile error at line 4, column 7_

Comment: In your procedure, why are you looping over a result set, only to create a very simple INSERT statment as text, then executing that text as dynamic sql?  (And in your example, your procedure never uses the two input parametes.)  The entire procedure could be reduced to a simple INSERT statement.  Oh, and the contents of a GTT will only be visable to the session that inserted them.  I don't know what your business case is, but from what I see here, I'd question your entire approach.

Comment: This code is still under development. Both arguments will be used inside WHERE clause :`WHERE TABLE_NAME = arg_table_name  AND TABLE_OWNER = arg_owner_name `. It is a part of bigger solution where I have to parse textlog for schema and table name which is always different. 'TABLEMASTER'.'TESTTABLE' is created only for  testing purposes.

My idea is to call from TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION my procedure using DBLINK which inserts records into GTT and then in the same procedure select GTT using same DBLINK to save results into variable.
But I can't execute procedure via DBLINK atm

Comment: @kerediws Perhaps the error message is wrong. This procedure creation line is incorrect and should not have parentheses at the end: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION()`.  (Or is that not the real code but only an example of the procedure declaration?)

Comment: @JonHeller it was my mistake, but `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLEMASTER.REPLICATE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION` doesn't work aswell (returns same error during compilation). Generally I can't execute `TABLEMASTER.INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');` via DBLINK. Quoting it like `"TABLEMASTER"."INSERT_PARTITION_RECORDS"@"SOURCELINK"('TABLEMASTER', 'TESTTABLE');` returns different error - identifier ... must be declared. I have no idea how to call procedure in external database using dblink. Procedure I am trying to call is compiled correctly and tested locally, but doesnt work remotely

Comment: **PROBLEM SOLVED** That was problem with my DBLINK - it was not public. After recreating DBLINK with public syntax I can access my procedure.

Thank You for every answer.

Comment: @kerediws Be very careful before using public database links. They are often considered a huge security risk and are one of the first thing a security audit will look for. Unless both databases are personal test machines that you don't care about, you probably shouldn't use public database links.